# How can SQL Server Always Encrypted feature work when both SQL Server and client software is on the same machine?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, encryption, always-encrypted

I'm working on a .NET Winforms application (VB.NET, .NET framework 4.5) that stores data in a SQL Server Express 2016 database; BOTH parts are running on the same machine.

Some of the columns in the database contain data that are sensitive and should not be available unencrypted to the user. So, I started looking for an efficient way to accomplish that. After some reading, I saw that the "new" Always Encrypted feature on the SQL Server is a quite efficient "out-of-the-box" way to implement this but with one catch... SQL server and client application must NOT be on the same machine since the certificate is stored in the local Windows Certificate Store.

My question: is there any way to do this without going to the Azure solution? The app must be able to work even if the PC is offline.

Any suggestions are welcomed. It's very important though that encryption must be as "light-weight" as possible, resources-wise. Thanks everyone in advance. Sorry if my English is not that good.

P.S. I tested this setup just to be sure and yes, you can decrypt the data through SSMS when both SQL Server and client application (with the certificate) are on the same machine.

Update: Check answer by Andrew. Big thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: You misunderstand what Always Encrypted does. It is intended to protect data at rest, to ensure that *only* the user has access to it, and not (say) the people who make the database backups. If you want data to actually be *unavailable* to a user, all you have to do is encrypt it with a key they don't have access to. Note that this necessarily makes it unavailable unencrypted to your application as well -- if that's not what you want you're looking at some sort of DRM scheme instead, and those are fundamentally breakable as an application can't do anything a user can't.

Comment: Your update should be an answer: it could be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by implementing custom AES encryption of the data from within the application (and quite efficiently actually).

The user can now see the data decrypted in the application but not through SSMS.